# where does the additional dimension of the Input in a keras.Model come from?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I define a model like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

input_shape = (20,20)
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

nn = layers.Flatten()(input)
nn = layers.Dense(10)(nn)
output = layers.Activation('sigmoid')(nn) 

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

Why do I need to add another dimension to my actual input:

```
actual_input = np.ones((1,20,20))
prediction = model.predict(actual_input)
```

why can't I just do `actual_input = np.ones((20,20))`?

Edit:

in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) it says something about batchsize.. Is this batchsize somehow related to my question? If so, why would I need it, when I want to predict with my model?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Keras` (`TensorFlow`), one cannot predict on a single input. Therefore, even if you have a single example, you need to add the `batch_axis` to it.

Practically, in this situation, you have a batch size of 1, hence the batch axis.

This is how `TensorFlow` and `Keras` are built, and even for a single prediction you need to add the batch axis (batch size of 1 == 1 single example).

You can use `np.expand_dims(input,axis=0)` or `tf.expand_dims(input,axis=0)` to transform your input into a suitable format for prediction.