# Why can I provide batchsize in tf.Model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a little confused about the documentation of [tensorflow.keras.Model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

it says there:

> batch_size: Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).

I thought, when I train (or predict with) my model, I have to provide some data and I have to do that in a batch anyway..

For example if my inputsize of my neural network is (2), then I could give:

```
inputs = np.ones((1,2))
my_model.fit(inputs, target_output)

#or this:
inputs = np.ones((10,2))
my_model.fit(inputs, target_output)

#but never this:
inputs = np.ones((2))
my_model.fit(inputs, target_output)
```

**my question:**

So when I call `my_model.fit()` why would I want to **additionally** provide `batch_size` if the batch I am providing within the call already has a defined size?

**Edit:** I have thought about it. If `inputs` is the data I put into `my_model.fit()` and let's say it contains 1000 examples, can I then specify that, of these 1000 I only want to use 100 (random?) examples for training with setting `batch_size=100`? If this should be true, why would I not just extract a sample beforehand and would only give this sample to `my_model.fit()`

convenience?

**Edit2:** I already know, that I need that additional dimension for the batchsize, as was answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67306409/where-does-the-additional-dimension-of-the-input-in-a-keras-model-come-from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to better generalize the learning, the network is going to look at the samples you provide in "batches". This is not the same as your entire dataset. If you have 1000 samples in total and a batch size of 100, the network will do a forward pass on 100 samples, then backpropagate based on those 100 samples, then a forward pass on the next 100 samples. Without this, the network would do a forward pass and then backpropogate either every individual sample, or all of the samples at once. Backpropagating for every individual sample makes the network too sensitive to each sample - you want it to learn based on features and patterns common across all samples.

Your batchsize then is a valuable hyperparameter to adjust how your model learns. You can encourage more generalization by increasing the batchsize, or encourage more specialization by decreasing the batch size. When you fit the model, you're saying "Here's all of my training data", then saying "look at it 64 samples at a time"

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Well that means, I had a completely wrong understanding of how batches work.. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

one of the reasons we use batch size is that we may have a large dataset and if we use **None**, our memory space whether on GPU or main memory, can not hold them.
now, if you use a summary of a CNN model, you will see that every **input tensors** have a shape

```
(None,height,width,channel)
```

that means, base on your batch size, the model will place a related number of images instead of **None**, based on this if you have a matrix like this

```
a = tf.ones((120,120,3))
```

and you input shape

```
(None,120,120,3)
```

there are many ways to pass it through the model, and on way to do this, expand your dimension on axis 0

```
a = tf.expand_dims(a,axis=0)
```

and after that, your shape will

```
print(a.shape())
(1,120,120,3)
```

finally, you cat pass or fit it on the model.

Comment: sorry, but this totally doesn't answer my question. I don't think, that you understood my question. I will try to make it more precise.